# Check if image exists, if not show default image using php

Tags: php, image, loops

I have tried file_exists and getimagesize but the page is loading very slowly so I wanted to try this way as below...
First, I'm getting list of all images using loop as below

```
foreach(glob('./images/*.png') as $filename){
           $ImagesArray[] = $filename;
           }
```

then I have another loop which generates divs after taking values from an another array. Inside this loop I'm checking whether image exists, if not choosing default image.

```
foreach ($populartags as $word => $count) {

$DefaultImage = './images/tag.png';

    if (in_array("./images/$word.png", $ImagesArray)){

            $DefaultImage = './images/'.$word.'.png'; }


....output image
}
```

But the result is: it's displaying only the images which exist in image folder. Then for others it's not showing default image.
What's wrong with this code??

Comment: Could you print_r($ImagesArray); for me please?

Comment: Please add an example with that in `$ImagesArray` can bem what you have in `$populartags`

Comment: We need to see what is in the $popuartags array before we can solve this :/

Comment: @ChrisEvans result is: Array ( [./qa-plugin/tags/images/ieor.png] => 0 [./qa-plugin/tags/images/tag.png] => 1 )

Comment: @Chris $populartags contains this: Array ( [university] => 2 [hello] => 2 [20] => 1 [19] => 1 [18] => 1 [17] => 1 [16] => 1 [15] => 1 [14] => 1 [13] => 1

Comment: @populartags contains words and a number.  like the word "university" was used twice so [university] => 2

Comment: @Sardor You have two $DefaultImage locations in your script. If the true default image is './images/tag.png', then it is being overridden in your else statement.

Comment: @Drakes oh yes i didn't mention that. I deleted else statement, it didn't change anything though

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simple use a htaccess rule for that?

Something like this will display the requested image, or else a default one, 
if the requested one does not exist (In this ase only `.gif` images):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.gif$
RewriteRule .* default.gif
```

Comment: As i know it shows the default image on all pages where images don't exist i don't want the default image appear on other pages.